# Check if data columns have the same data in R, return a colour change

Tags: r, dplyr, gt

I am trying to see if data is the same column-wise but within a pair of rows. Instead of creating a new column indicating match/no match, I want the original cells to be coloured green for match and red for no match. Is this possible in R? I can do a similar thing in excel but I do not want to create to new column so wanted to see if this is possible in R.

```
df1 <- structure (list(
  subject_id = c("191-3456", "191-3456", "191-0021", "191-0021", "191-0741", "191-0741"), 
  visit_point = c("3-month","3-month","6-month","6-month","3-month","3-month"),
  source_name = c("6730.csv", "0956.csv", "6730.csv", "0956.csv", "6730.csv", "0956.csv"), 
  ipv = c("6", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2"), 
  epds = c("0", "4", "0", "0", "3", "3"), 
  consent_date = c("2022-10-27", "2022-10-20", "2023-01-19", "2023-01-19", "2023-01-19", "2023-01-17"), 
  bisq = c ("17:00","18:00","16:00","16:00","02:00", "02:00" )), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

desired data:
I indicated the colours in brackets.

| subject_id | visit_point | source_name | ipv | epds | consent_date | bisq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 191-3456 | 3-month | 6730.csv | 6 (red) | 0 (red) | 2022-10-27 (red) | 17:00 (red) |
| 191-3456 | 3-month | 0956.csv | 1 (red) | 4 (red) | 2022-10-20 (red) | 18:00 (red) |
| 191-0021 | 6-month | 6730.csv | 1 (green) | 0 (green) | 2023-01-19 (green) | 16:00 (green) |
| 191-0021 | 6-month | 0956.csv | 1 (green) | 0 (green) | 2023-01-19 (green) | 16:00 (green) |
| 191-0741 | 3-month | 6730.csv | 2 (green) | 3 (green) | 2023-01-19 (red) | 02:00 (green) |
| 191-0741 | 3-month | 0956.csv | 2 (green) | 3 (green) | 2023-01-17 (red) | 02:00 (green) |

Essentially the variables epds, ipv, consent_date, and bisq, should be the same data when pulling from either source, but in some cases it isn't (as seen in df).

Comment: It's doable but it would be a display only - there is no associated 'colour' with the underlying data in R.  I would suggest adding it as an additional column, then when you display your data you can leave that column out of the display but use it for colouring the background.   If you really want to try and do it as one step, I know the `GT` package has a `data_color()` function that can do row-wise colouring based on a logical vector or row numbers etc.

Comment: How can I add the additional column in this case?

Comment: Ah, in your original question you seemed to be asking for row-wise comparisons, but your example shows it's actually comparing each column within a pair of rows.  I'll have a think about an appropriate approach.

Comment: Please clarify "everything should be exactly the same", except that it's not literally everything, since no rows here are duplicated. So you mean perhaps "all except `source_name`"? or "all number-like fields" (including dates)? or something else?

Comment: I edited the question. Hope it's clearer.